# Why does the Bartlett test from scipy.stats.bartlett gives nan as output?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, statsmodels, anova

My data is:

```
data=[[2,2,2,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1],[3,3,3,3]]
```

When I pass like this:

```
bartlett(*data)
```

It gives output as `(nan,nan)`
Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bartlett test is for testing the homogeneity of variance across groups, in your case, there are no variance, as all the groups contain equal values.

A minimal example:

```
In [7]:

import scipy.stats as ss
In [8]:

data=[[2,2,2,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1],[3,3,3,3]]
ss.bartlett(*data)
Out[8]:
(nan, nan)
In [9]:

A=[10,7,20,14,14,12,10,23,17,20,14,13,11,17,21,11,16,14,17,17,19,21,7]
B=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,]
ss.bartlett(A, B)
Out[9]:
(47.7068477814218, 4.9495974630644599e-12)
```

So it is not a bug.

Comment: But it should give probability as 1 right? because there is no variance and hence the null hypothesis is correct

Comment: No, p value = 1 should be reserved for cases like `A=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]; B=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]` where the variance are truly the same (and variance are none-zero). `nan` sort of serve as a error message indicating the variance are 0.